# Hiding getting elapsed time in C

Tags: c

I need to hide the instructions to get the elapsed time in C. For example in the next code there are several line instructions to get the elapsed time of the function foo.

```
struct timeval start_keygen, end_keygen;
long int diff_keygen_sec = 0;
gettimeofday(&start_keygen, NULL);
foo(r, w, h);
gettimeofday(&end_keygen, NULL);
timediff(start_keygen, end_keygen, &diff_keygen_sec);
```

My question is How to hide that several lines in one function, for example in "getTime", i.e:

```
getTime(foo(r,w,h))
```

Comment: although ugly, how about a macro?

Comment: @m.s. It's not ugly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a macro:

```
#define TIME(e, res) do{struct timeval start_keygen, end_keygen; \
            res = 0; \
            gettimeofday(&start_keygen, NULL); \
            e; \
            gettimeofday(&end_keygen, NULL); \
            timediff(start_keygen, end_keygen, &res)} while(0)  \
```

Then you can do:

```
long int myRes;
TIME(foo(r,w,h), myRes);
```

This will expand into the code that you have, each time it is used at compile time and will bind the result to `myRes`.

Answer (score 2):

A macro is really what you want, but instead of passing the function call, you can make it a little bit different, it's syntactically similar to a function, which is less ugly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TimedExecution(elapsed, function, ...)               \
    do {                                                     \
        struct timeval start;                                \
        struct timeval end;                                  \
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);                          \
        function(__VA_ARGS__);                               \
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);                            \
        *((long int *) elapsed) = timevaldiff(&start, &end); \
    } while (0)

long int
timevaldiff(struct timeval *starttime, struct timeval *finishtime)
 {
    long int msec;

    msec  = (finishtime->tv_sec  - starttime->tv_sec ) * 1000;
    msec += (finishtime->tv_usec - starttime->tv_usec) / 1000;

    return msec;
 }

void 
execute(const char *message)
 {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
     {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", message);
        sleep(1);
     }
 }

int
main(void)
 {
    long int elapsed;
    TimedExecution(&elapsed, execute, "Hello World!");
    fprintf(stdout, "Executed in: %ld msec\n", elapsed);
    return 0;
 }
```